# Deployment to Sandbox vs Deployment to Prod

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, code-coverage, sandbox

I have a simple question - why do apex tests not run when you deploy between two sandboxes? My assumption is the amount of time it will take to run, but is there another better reason? Is there a way to run all tests on a sandbox to sandbox deployment without using the migration tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likely reason the default test level for deployments between sandboxes is simple: convenience. However, you can always tweak the test level.

After you click the <kbd>Deploy</kbd> button:

[image: Deploy Button]

You have a choice:

[image: Choose a Test Option]

You are looking for **Run Local Tests**:

> All tests in your organization are run, except the ones that originate from installed managed packages. This test level is the default for production deployments that include Apex classes or triggers.